# Coloring separate cell based on matching of data in two rows

Tags: excel

I am hoping someone can help me. I am using Excel 2010.

I want to color cell `K1` when the values in cell `C1:J1` match `C2:J2`. I cant color the cell with the actual data on them as they are already colored based on the type of data they hold or where it came from.

Comment: Look up conditional formatting. If you're still having trouble, post specifics, don't just ask people to do everything for you.

Comment: I did look up conditional formatting and it doesn't allow it to actually colour a single cell that is not a part of the equation. I also would not have posted it if I had not already tried to do that. I have looked up many forums and tried similar things people have posted however its always colouring a cell within the targeted areas and not outside.

Comment: My specifics I posted. I have a range of values for different products. 

When a shipment comes in, I enter in the shipped goods (as I get multiple shipments to fulfil my order. 

When the values of what was requested matches what has been finally accepted, I want my order number to colour it completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a conditional format on K1, with the formula

```
  =AND(C1=C2,D1=D2,E1=E2,F1=F2,G1=G2,H1=H2,I1=I2,J1=J2)
```

determining whether to display the format.

To do this, select cell `K1` and:

- Click `Conditional Formatting` from the `Home` ribbon, and then click `New Rule`.
- Choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.
- Enter the formula in the entry box below the words `Format values where this formula is true.`
- Select the fill color format you want to apply and click `OK`.